# Why Safari doesn't support http2

Tags: safari, http2

http2 has many advantages over http/1.1. it's possible the next generation http protocol, that at least worth researching and trying.

current popular web browser like Chrome already support it, but why safari didn't support it.

Comment: Corresponds to Safari do supports HTTP/2: on OSX 10.11+ only and on iOS 9: http://caniuse.com/#search=http2 . It's like Microsoft supports HTTP/2 in IE11 only on Windows 10. Why? Mostly because of design of the web browser: which part do the web browser and which part do the OS. Chrome have another design and it's probably the best web browser currently.

Answer (score 3):

Safari has supported HTTP/2 for nearly a year now on the latest Mac OS 10.11.  Both Safari 9 and 9.1.

From:  http://alexwlchan.net/2015/09/http2-by-stealth/

It turns out that Apple announced support for HTTP/2 all the way back in June, at WWDC: Networking with NSURLSession (start at the 13 minute mark). The same session introduced App Transport Security (HTTPS by default for all apps), and I suspect that overshadowed this announcement. It doesn’t help that I’ve found almost no mention of it in Apple’s developer docs.

But the crux is this:

As of iOS 9 and El Capitan, all NSURLSession requests can support HTTP/2. (And if you’ve been running the developer seeds, you’ve had it for a while.)

Apple have been using this themselves: remote access to HomeKit devices via iCloud all goes via HTTP/2. And I wouldn’t be surprised if they start using it to push out software updates, given that CDNs were explicitly called out as an HTTP/2 provider in that session.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12352303)

Comment: @Bono Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Maybe it supports but it behaves differently than chrome for example. It does not load resources which are subdomains(CNAME's to be correct). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253779/safari-wont-load-some-resources-over-http-2

Comment: but the problem is the AWS alb HTTP2 has been giving me problems. I am forced to disable it